# How to display blog post in wordpress?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, themes

I have a wordpress theme "Hatch", and I'm doing it for my photography. I usually do websites with HTML/CSS (in Dreamweaver), and this is the first time doing Wordpress.

In My homepage, you can see the recent posts as thumbnails. I'm thinking of creating a new menu, called 'Blog', basically just like what normal themes do, displaying blog posts. It might be something simple, but i just can't find what to code to make the posts display as normal display .

the website is lizettephotography.com

thanks heaps!

Liz

Comment: You might get more responses or find better anwers on the [Wordpress StackExchange](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to code. 
Create new category "Blog". Add that category to your main menu.

After that add new post to Blog category. on click  blog menu link will show all post having blog category.

You need to format post design as you want.

**EDIT :**

In order to activate “post formats” in WordPress 3.1+, you will need to open your theme’s functions.php file and paste the following code:

```
add_theme_support( 'post-formats', array( 'aside', 'gallery' ) );
```

Note: aside, and gallery are not the only available post formats. The available list of post formats are:

aside – Typically styled blog format.

chat – A chat transcript.

gallery – A gallery of images.

link – A link to another site.

image – A single image.

quote – A quotation.

status – A short status update, usually limited to 140 characters. Similar to a Twitter status update.

video – A single video.

For the full list of post formats, refer to WordPress Codex.
Once you have added this code, you will see a new field in your post write panel in the right hand column where you see publish.

Upon writing the post, you can change the format and hit publish. This will allow you to display your post in a pre-styled format.

Edit your post loop.

Suppose in your case blog category post format is **asid**

We are going to be utilizing the conditional tag: has_post_format()

```
if ( has_post_format( 'aside' ) {

  // Blog Category format

} 
else 
{

   // Normal Formate

}
```

I hope this will help you. [More Info...](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Formats)

Comment: hi Ajay, thanks for that. i just did that. my question is,  how do i format 'Blog' Category to display the posts as full width posts? Do i need to create a new template?

Comment: hi ajay, thanks for that. im gonna give it a try later. anyway,  a question will be : if i do that, will the 'home' posts be affected? cos i like how the home page is that 'featured images' boxes, i just want an additional menu, 'blog' , to do the same things just with different viewing basically..

Comment: where do  i put this : if ( has_post_format( 'aside' ) {

  // Blog Category format

} 
else 
{

   // Normal Formate

} ?